# Interned dictionary values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am playing with `string.Intern()` to solve my problem: a dictionary with a huge number of keys and a small number of values. Various keys lead to the same values (in theory), but in practice each value is different. I don't want that, since this is a huge waste. I ***really*** need to do interning. I am aware that it will last for the entire lifespan of an application. This is not only acceptable but even desirable.

So I tried writing `InternedDictionary` for this purpose, but it does not seem to work. Why? The memory consumption seems to be the same with and without `string.Intern(x)` in line marked with the `*` sign. How to improve it then?

```
public class InternedDictionary : Dictionary<int, string>
{
    new public void Add(int key, string value)
    {
        base.Add(key, string.Intern(value));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 1000000;

    var dict = new InternedDictionary();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(i, new string('x', (i % 10) * 1000));
    }

    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the string aren't already interned (with `String.IsInterned`) when not explicitely interning them (and so interning them won't do anything **more** than what already is) ?

Comment: What's the problem with wasting memory? Are you running out?

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert on the topic to answer, but given the size of your strings, it wouldn't surprise to find that most of them wind up allocated in the large-object heap. Also, be sure that you are measuring the right thing. The _process_ memory consumption may well not go down, even if all of your string data winds up interned. A million allocations can actually be satisfied very quickly, temporarily pushing heap size up; your memory usage at the end of the run may just be mostly empty space.

Comment: I think this is a better way to create your new class:  `public class InternedDictionary: Dictionary<int, String>
{
        new public void Add(int key, string value)
    {
        base.Add(key, string.Intern(value)); 
    }
}`

Comment: @Randolph - So you're a long way away from the 2GB limit. Is it really worth worrying about?

Comment: It definitely works, because when I try running it without the `string.Intern` call, I'm getting `OutOfMemoryException`, and it works just fine with interning.

Comment: I tested both a normal dictionary and the InternedDictionary with strings entered from a textbox.  In BOTH cases the strings were interned so I don't see how you gain anything.